# Need to show daterangepicker (calendar) before clicking the input element, when the Html page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, scripting

I am working with a template and I relocate the daterangepicker at the left menu and I'd like to show it when the page is load, but there are lots of default functions and one of them shows it until I click the input element up of it. Any ideas?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="daterangepicker xdisplay picker_2 single opensright show-calendar">
    <div class="calendar first single right" style="display: block;">                            
    </div>                        
  </div>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="col-md-12 xdisplay_inputx form-group has-feedback">
          <input type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left active" id="single_cal2" placeholder="First Name" aria-describedby="inputSuccess2Status2">
          <span class="fa fa-calendar-o form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span id="inputSuccess2Status2" class="sr-only">(success)</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Here is the script in the HTML:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 

    $('#single_cal2').daterangepicker({         
      singleDatePicker: true,
      calender_style: "picker_2"
    }, function(start, end, label) {
      console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
    });        
  });
</script>
```

And here is the click command in the js file:

```
this.element.is("input")?this.element.on({
            "click.daterangepicker":i.proxy(this.show,this),
            "focus.daterangepicker":i.proxy(this.show,this),
            "keyup.daterangepicker":i.proxy(this.updateFromControl,this)
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no option to show it on page load, you need to emulate click on input

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#single_cal2').daterangepicker({         
      singleDatePicker: true,
      calender_style: "picker_2"
    }, function(start, end, label) {
      console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
    });    

    $('#single_cal2').click();

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard **HTML DOM click() Method** you could use after the document has loaded. It simulates a mouse click on an element.

A simple example from [w3school.com: HTML DOM click() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp)

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").click();
}
```

```html
<p>Hover over the checkbox to simulate a mouse-click.</p>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onmouseover="myFunction()" onclick="alert('click event occured')">
</form>
```